# Blocking pictures and videos on particular site

Tags: google-chrome

What is the best way to prevent load pictures and videos in Chrome browser on particular site in order to block possibility malicious redirections to javascript or php scripts?

Comment: "malicious php script"? You know PHP is executed on the server, not in the web browser?

Comment: Via web-proxy. Depends on your web traffic what kind of proxy you'd use. If it's corporation then there's plenty of appliances. If it's home network then maybe Squid (but I am not sure if it's fit for purpose), and on desktop you could use PrivProxy. However, since most websites are going SSL - browser extension would be the best fit I think. You'd need to find out what would be the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension like [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) in conjunction with some Chrome settings.

Under `chrome://settings/content` you can choose to block images on all sites or `manage exceptions` and block images on certain sites. Similarly, you can also prevent JavaScript from running on all or certain sites.

[image: Chrome Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Safescript it is a Chrome extensions that will block alot of items in a webpage and has alot of options.